# Displaying Hover Information on POINT Data in Pyviz/ hvplot

Tags: geopandas, pyviz, hvplot

https://hvplot.pyviz.org/user_guide/Geographic_Data.html

In the Geopandas section you can find two examples displaying Data, but only the second one, with 'Polygon' Geodata intead of 'Points', is presenting all of the extra Information from the geopandas file, while hovering over the Map.

I've tried to manipulate the Points to Polygons but hope there is a better solution.

[geopandas hover Information only lat,lon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eflz4.png)

[geopandas hover Information complete Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWrwA.png)

Comment: Could you please be more specific? It is customary to provide 1) a reproducible example that may allow others to run the same code and 2) the versions of software that you are running.  Alternatively, if the software is in development it might be more useful to ask the contributors at their github repo., https://github.com/pyviz/hvplot     Thank you

Comment: Every one of the plots on that page shows hover information, for me, in Mac OS X Chrome.